# laravel send notification using pusher beams

Tags: laravel, pusher

i wrote a test,but every time execute it,i got same error,

> Unauthorized: Incorrect Secret Key {"userId":153,"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Unauthorized: Incorrect Secret Key at /var/www/panel/vendor/pusher/pusher-push-notifications/src/PushNotifications.php:100)

how to solve it?

Comment: you can try with clear the cache and check again.

Comment: i tried every clear possible in artisan,but not work

Comment: Did you set "instanceId" and "secretKey" in env file?

Comment: yes,and also writing that in config file,and in my code call that from config('')

Comment: Did you try by restart the server or system? I think sometimes the env variable is not correctly pickup by the framework.

Comment: restart my server,but it's not work

Comment: You might consider raising a support ticket at support.pusher.com, including as much information as possible so they can help.